# What is the range of this function: (sin(x)+tanh(x))/(1+sin(x)tanh(x))?

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, hyperbolic-functions

I don't really have any idea how to solve this problem. It appears to have horizontal asymptotes at values of $x=1$ and $x=-1$ but I have no way of proving these. I have taken the derivative (an unwieldy thing) and i don't see any way of solving it for zero without the use of a program. Any solution or insight is welcome and greatly appreciated.

Comment: i would try to work with the representations of $sin, cos, sinh$ and $cosh$  by the exponential function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_functions#Relationship_to_exponential_function_and_complex_numbers and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_function#Standard_analytic_expressions no garantee that it works but maybe it does

Comment: The graph of the function is *very* similar to the graph of $y=tanh(2x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both $\sin , \tanh $ are bounded within same range $ \pm 1$ and both have common domain $ -\infty < x < \infty $. With such sign combination considering numerator/ denominator it will not affect the common range $\pm 1.$

Answer (score 1):

The denumerator is never zero, so this function is continuous. Also by a simple check you can see that it is also differentiable. By solving $f'(x) = 0$ you will find that the global extrema  happen when $\sin x = \pm 1$, where $f(x) = \pm 1$. By continuity the range is $[-1, 1]$.

Comment: How did you solve f'(x) for zero?

Comment: When you differentiate, if I remember correctly, you immediately find one solution $\cos x = 0$. If you assume that is not the case and simplify you find another answer $\cos x = -1$ and those are the only local extrema. There is some algebra involved though. Turns out $\cos x = -1$, although being a local extrema is not a global one (just by plugging in, nothing fancy).

Comment: +1: $$f'(x)=-\frac{\mathrm{cos}\left( x\right) \left( \mathrm{cos}\left( x\right) +1\right)  \left( {{\mathrm{tanh}\left( x\right) }^{2}}-1\right) }{{{\left( 1+\mathrm{sin}\left( x\right)  \mathrm{tanh}\left( x\right) \right) }^{2}}}$$ with zeros when $\cos(x)=0,-1$, i.e. when $f(x)=\pm1 \text{ or }f(x)=\tanh(x) \in [-1,1]$.  The zeros when $\cos(x)=-1$ are in fact points of inflection.

Answer (score 0):

Since
$\tanh(a+b)
=\frac{\tanh(a)+\tanh(b)}{1+\tanh(a)\tanh(b)}
$,
if
$\sin(x)
=\tanh(y)
$,
this is
$\frac{\tanh(y)+\tanh(x)}{1+\tanh(y)\tanh(x)}
=\tanh(x+y)
=\tanh(x+\tanh^{(-1)}(\sin(x)))
$.

Since the range of
$\sin(x)$
is
$[-1, 1]$,
the range of
$\tanh^{(-1)}(\sin(x))$
is
$(-\infty, \infty)$
as is the range of
$x+\tanh^{(-1)}(\sin(x))$.

Therefore the range of
$\tanh(x+\tanh^{(-1)}(\sin(x)))
$
is
$(-\infty, \infty)$.

If the value for
$x = \pi/2$
is considered to be
$\infty$,
we might allow $\infty$
to be reached.

I found seeing the plots of
the various components
(in Wolfy)
to be interesting.